# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, win8

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

On win7 my application work properly. But when I try run this on win8 I get an error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=2.0.0.0

System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll is copy local during publish.
If it is important, I migrate from mvc4 to mvc5 a while time ago.

Stack Trace:

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' lub jednej z jego zależności.
>   Zlokalizowana definicja manifestu zestawu nie odpowiada odwołaniu do
>   zestawu. (Wyjątek od HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Metoda Start w typie
>   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartCode, wywoływana na
>   etapie inicjalizacji przed uruchomieniem aplikacji, zgłosiła wyjątek;
>   komunikat o błędzie: Nie można załadować pliku lub zestawu
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' lub jednej z jego zależności.
>   Zlokalizowana definicja manifestu zestawu nie odpowiada odwołaniu do
>   zestawu. (Wyjątek od HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1
>   methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +12618627
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods) +12618348
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +280
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Metoda Start w typie
>   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartCode, wywoływana na
>   etapie inicjalizacji przed uruchomieniem aplikacji, zgłosiła wyjątek;
>   komunikat o błędzie: Nie można załadować pliku lub zestawu
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' lub jednej z jego zależności.
>   Zlokalizowana definicja manifestu zestawu nie odpowiada odwołaniu do
>   zestawu. (Wyjątek od HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12617668
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12457285

root Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="aprSection" type="APRLibrary.Configuration.APRWebSectionWithBaseLogin, APRLibrary" />
  </configSections>
  <aprSection configSource="APRTeam.config" />
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxQueryStringLength="6048" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Error.cshtml">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error.cshtml"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/error?status=403"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error?status=404"/>
    </customErrors>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
        <add namespace="APRTeamGrafikMVC4.Code.Helpers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="6048" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Views web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I get this sometime sand find if I wait about 30 seconds and hit refresh it goes away, have you tried this?

Comment: Dll version conflict occurs.

Comment: Uninstall Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc and install it again. And then Rebuild the Project.

Comment: @JMK - refreshing doesn't work

Comment: @CodingDefined - I have VS on win7 and work fine, I publish my project and run it on other comuter with win7 and work fine, but on win8 it does't.

Comment: @user1031034 `<section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />` it is 3.0.0.0 but somewhere it is refrencing 2.0.0.0

Comment: @CodingDefined I don't find 2.0.0.0 in my application. If somewhere is wrong refrencing I should get error every time. On win7 it work...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I update

```
Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem occurred when you **update** **NuGet** packages or anything. Since the **update happens in package/dll respective version updated** should be included in **web config**.  Unfortunately, it is not reflected on the web config resulting conflict in the .dll file version and web config version resulting above error.

**Solution:**

Step 1: Go to Project Solution **Explorer-> Reference ->** System.Web.WebPages.Razor(Any reference throwing error)

Step 2: **Right-click-> properties**

Step 3: In properties, you will find **Version: X.X.X.X** (3.0.0.0 or 2.0.0.0)
This version is the actual version loaded in the project.

Step 4: Now, go to Web.config file (Web config in Views folder)
find the System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=X.X.X.X line.
Then, change the Version to Version number which you found in reference properties in **step 3**.

Now, run the code the problem should go away.